# iOS: NSURLRequest returns the same page each time on different storyboards

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios6, xcode4.5

I have a `UIWebView` class that is added to each storyboard on load, but when passing into this class the page I require form the parent `ViewController` it only show the file from the first ever page and on each different page/viewController its the same even though I set it different on each.

Is it somehow caching this page and if so, how can I have a clean `UIWebview` everytime?

my UIwebview class m file (ContentView.m):

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         NSString *urlpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pageToDisplay ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"pageContent"];
          NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:urlpath];
          NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

          [self loadRequest:request];
       }
      return self;
  }
```

My Parent view passes the requested page using the following variable `pageToDisplay`:

Parent View m file:

```
  #import "ContentView.h"

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        ContentView *dispalyPageContent = [[ContentView alloc] init];
         [dispalyPageContent setPageToDisplay:@"THEpg1"];
         [self.view addSubview:dispalyPageContent];
          //-- 
         [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

For each other parent view the code is the same but the `[displayPageContent setPageToDisplay:@"THEpg1"];` which should change the page I want, e.g. next view would be [displayPageContent setPageToDisplay:@"THEpg2"];

Is it possible to clear this and load a fresh request each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you call `ContentView *dispalyPageContent = [[ContentView alloc] init];` in your `viewDidLoad` , you init it with:

```
NSString *urlpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pageToDisplay ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"pageContent"];
```

And in pathForResource:pageToDisplay  at the moment of initializing is some trash.

And then, when you call `[dispalyPageContent setPageToDisplay:@"smth"]` , it changes nothing, because your class `ContentView` has been already inited with some trash in `PageToDisplay`

(Also, you call `[[ContentView alloc] init];` and in your code there is only  `initWithFrame:...` for objects of `ContentView` class)

You can solve this in this way:
1) in your ContentView.m

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame pageToDisp:(NSString *)pageToDisp {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
         NSString *urlpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pageToDisp ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"pageContent"];
          NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:urlpath];
          NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

          [self loadRequest:request];
       }
      return self;
  }
```

2) In your ContentView.h:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame pageToDisp:(NSString *)pageToDisp
```

3) And then, in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        ContentView *dispalyPageContent = [[ContentView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame pageToDisp:@"THEpg1"];

         [self.view addSubview:dispalyPageContent];
          //-- 
         [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply but I get this error: No visible @interface for 'ContentView' declares the selector 'pageToDisp: using the following ContentView *dispalyPageContent = [[ContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 60, 300, 300) pageToDisp:@"THEpg1"]; thanks

Comment: Apologise looking at the code I might have missed the extra variable at the end of the initwithframe method, will try again when I get back in and let you know thanks